# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. newBitmap был null

Tags: c#

Написал алгоритм для изменения контрастности изображения, но выдает данную ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить ошибку?

Код для программы

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap newBitmap;
    Image file;
    Boolean opened = false;
    float contrast = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void открытьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK) // Если в диалоге была нажата кнопка ОК
        {
            file = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog1.FileName); // Загружаем изображение
            pictureBox1.Image = file;
            opened = true;
        }
    }

    private void сохранитьToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null) // Если изображение в picturebox1 есть
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog(); // Диалог для выбора файлов
            sfd.Filter = "Image Files (*.JPG;*.PNG) | *.JPG;*.PNG"; // Фильтр файлов
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // Если нажата кнопка ОК
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(sfd.FileName); // Сохраняем изображение
            }
        }
    }

    private void оттенкиСерогоToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            Bitmap input = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); // Создаем Bitmap из изображения, который находится в pictureBox1
            Bitmap output = new Bitmap(input.Width, input.Height); // Создаём Bitmap для черно-белого изображения
            for (int j = 0; j < input.Height; j++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < input.Width; i++)
                {
                    // Получаем (i,j) пиксель
                    UInt32 pixel = (UInt32)(input.GetPixel(i, j).ToArgb());
                    // Получаем компоненты цветов пикселя
                    float R = (float)((pixel & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
                    float G = (float)((pixel & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
                    float B = (float)((pixel & 0x000000FF));
                    // Делаем цвет черно-белым (оттенок серого) - находим их среднее арифметическое
                    R = G = B = (R + G + B) / 3.0f;
                    // Собираем новый пиксель по частям
                    UInt32 newPixel = 0xFF000000 | ((UInt32)R << 16) | ((UInt32)G << 8) | ((UInt32)B);
                    // Добавляем его в Bitmap нового изображения
                    output.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb((int)newPixel));                      
                }
                // Выводим черно-белое изображение из Bitmap в PictureBox1
            pictureBox1.Image = output;
        }
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString();
        int r, g, b;
        var image = new PictureBox();
        var loadImage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        var WidthHeightImage = new Bitmap(loadImage.Width, loadImage.Height);

        for (int j = 0; j < loadImage.Height; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < loadImage.Width; i++)
            {
                Color pixel = loadImage.GetPixel(i, j);
                r = pixel.R + trackBar1.Value;
                if (r > 255) r = 255; if (r < 0) r = 0;
                g = pixel.G + trackBar1.Value;
                if (g > 255) g = 255; if (g < 0) g = 0;
                b = pixel.B + trackBar1.Value;
                if (b > 255) b = 255; if (b < 0) b = 0;
                Color res = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
                WidthHeightImage.SetPixel(i, j, res);
            }
        pictureBox1.Image = WidthHeightImage;
        image.Image = WidthHeightImage;

    }

    private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label4.Text = trackBar2.Value.ToString();

        contrast = 0.04f * trackBar2.Value;
        
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();

        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]{
            new float[]{contrast,0f,0f,0f,0f },
            new float[]{0f,contrast,0f,0f,0f },
            new float[]{0f,0f,contrast,0f,0f },
            new float[]{0f,0f,0f,1f,0f },
            new float[]{0.001f,0.001f,0.001f,0f,1f}});

        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);

        g.DrawImage(newBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height), 0, 0, newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel,ia);
        g.Dispose();
        ia.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = bm;
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: `Bitmap newBitmap;` ты нигде не придаешь значения данной переменой, вот она у тебя и null. Мб ты хотел забыл инициализировать её `Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(500,500)`?

Comment: А разве я не загружаю в newBitmap ширину и высоту изображения?
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(newBitmap.Width, newBitmap.Height);

Comment: здесь ты пытаешься создать новый обьект Bitmap `bm` указывая ширину и высоту пустого newBitmap который не был инициализирован .

Comment: Да, действительно, больше исключения не выдает. Но при изменении контрастности просто изображение исчезает, странно...